# Ros2 robot won't move sideways with dwb or mppi controllers

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, path-planning, nav2, ros2-controllers

I am unable to get the mppi or dwb controllers to move in the Y direction.  If I set a goal that is close to the current position parallel to the current robot heading, the robot will shimmy back and forth until it eventually reaches the goal.  When using the mppi controller, I get a reasonable motion path when switching to DiffDrive

The cmd_vel messages do not contain a y component.  If I issue cmd_vel messages with a y component manually, the robot will move sideways.

I built ROS2 from source on the humble branch. I was able to obtain sideways motions using the dwb controller in galactic.  I do not believe that I changed my project file but I am not completely sure.

Here are the current parameters:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.02
    alpha2: 0.02
    alpha3: 0.02
    alpha4: 0.02
    alpha5: 0.02
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.05
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    initial_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "omnidirectional"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    set_initial_pose: True
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: .3
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node


bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False


controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25

    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.1
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 0.26
      vx_min: -0.26
      vy_max: 0.26
      wz_max: 1.9
      wz_min: -1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 1.7
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "Omni"
      visualize: true
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic", "PathAlignCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 4
        cost_weight: 10.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.5
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 4
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.5
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.0
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.05
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 14.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        offset_from_furthest: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        forward_preference: true
      # TwirlingCritic:
      #   enabled: true
      #   twirling_cost_power: 1
      #   twirling_cost_weight: 10.0

      # DWB parameters
      #plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      #debug_trajectory_details: True
      #min_vel_x: -0.26
      #min_vel_y: -0.26
      #max_vel_x: 0.26
      #max_vel_y: 0.26
      #max_vel_theta: 2.0
      #min_speed_xy: 0.0
      #max_speed_xy: 0.26
      #min_speed_theta: 0.0
      #acc_lim_x: 0.5
      #acc_lim_y: 0.5
      #acc_lim_theta: 0.5
      #decel_lim_x: -0.5
      #decel_lim_y: -0.5
      #decel_lim_theta: -0.5
      #vx_samples: 20
      #vy_samples: 5
      #vtheta_samples: 20
      #sim_time: 1.7
      #linear_granularity: 0.05
      #angular_granularity: 0.025
      #transform_tolerance: 0.2
      #xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      #trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      #short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      #stateful: True
      #footprint: "[ [0.305, 0.298], [0.305, -0.298], [-0.305, -0.298], [-0.305, 0.298] ]"
      #critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist", "ObstacleFootprint"]
      ##BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      #PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      #PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      #GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      #GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      #PathDist.scale: 32.0
      #GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      #RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      #RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      #RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0


controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0 
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 10
      height: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint: "[ [0.305, 0.298], [0.305, -0.298], [-0.305, -0.298], [-0.305, 0.298] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 4.0 # A lower value will increase the cost further out
        inflation_radius: 1.0
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: true
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.305, 0.298], [0.305, -0.298], [-0.305, -0.298], [-0.305, 0.298] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 10.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 9.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 2.0
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "turtlebot3_world.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 10.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:

      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerLattice"
      allow_unknown: true                 # Allow traveling in unknown space
      tolerance: 0.25                     # dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found.
      max_iterations: 1000000             # Maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
      max_planning_time: 5.0              # Max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 7.0       # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0  # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      reverse_penalty: 0.0                # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.3                # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 5.0          # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                   # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      rotation_penalty: 0.0               # Penalty to apply to in-place rotations, if minimum control set contains them
      retrospective_penalty: 0.5
      lattice_filepath: "/home/dcb/ros2_ws/src/basic_mobile_robot/config/output.json"                # The filepath to the state lattice graph
      lookup_table_size: 20.0             # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: false     # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      allow_reverse_expansion: false      # If true, allows the robot to use the primitives to expand in the mirrored opposite direction of the current robot's orientation (to reverse).
      smooth_path: True                   # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true
        refinement_num: 2


planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    
waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 2
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
    
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:

    # Plugin params
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    mode: mapping #localization

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 100.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
    enable_interactive_mode: true

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: true
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 100
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 100.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true
```